# ReactJS: get button 'value' on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I'm creating buttons using `map` to loop over an array. Each button is an item in the array. I'm also using `React.createElement` to create each button.

```js
['NICK', 'NKJR', 'NKTNS'].map(function (brand) {
  return React.createElement('button', {
    onClick: (e) => { console.log(e.target) }
  }, brand)
})
```

..however, for the `onClick` listener, how do I pass in the 'value' for each button?

For example, I'm trying to get the `console.log` to log 'NICK', 'NKJR' or 'NKTNS' depending on which button is clicked. Right now when I click a button it just logs `<button>NICK</button>` for example (I want 'NICK')

Comment: `brand` is already in scope of your click handler definition so why not just directly use it? Otherwise, you could use `e.target.textContent` or `e.target.value` though YMMV on that last one if you don't also directly assign `value: brand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should have access to the brand value by doing this:

```
onClick: () => {console.log(brand)}}
```

Since the value of brand is accessing within the .map() you are doing